# Hive on Spark in Mapr Distribution

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, mapr

Currently we are working on Hive, which by default uses map reduce as processing framework in our MapR cluster. Now we want to change from map reduce to spark for better performance. As per my understanding we need to set hive.execution.engine=spark.

Now my question is Hive on spark is currently supported by MapR ? if yes, what are configuration changes that we need to do ?

Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, MapR (5.2) doesn't support that. From their [docs](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/EcosystemRN/HiveRN-2.1.1-1703.html),

> MapR does not support Hive on Spark. Therefore, you cannot use Spark as an execution engine for Hive. However, you can run Hive and Spark on the same cluster. You can also use Spark SQL and Drill to query Hive tables.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I know and understand that your question is about using Spark as data processing engine for Hive; and as you can see in the various answer it is today not officially supported by MapR.

However, if you goal is to make Hive faster, and do not use MapReduce you can switch to Tez, for this install the MEP 3.0.

See: http://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/Hive/HiveandTez.html